# Check if false then run code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to test something. If `false` do this. I wish not to test for true, only false. My code looks like this and I only need to do something if false:

```
if Model.exists?(table_column: 'joe')
  # this part is blank
else
# run this code
end
```

My code runs after the `else` which is what I want. Is there a clean rails/ruby method that tests for false? My code would only run if false, not true.

If duplicate, I'll gladly delete. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `unless`

```
unless Model.exists?(table_column: 'joe')
  # run code
end
```

or `if not`

```
if not Model.exists?(table_column: 'joe') 
  # run code
end
```

or

```
if Model.find_by(table_column: 'joe').blank?
  # run code
end
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I was never a big fan of `unless`. Any other way? If not, looks good to me.

Comment: @Sylar:  `unless` is sugar for `if !(expression)`.  It negates the expression without the need to specify the `!` there.

Comment: You can use `if not`, if you don't want to use `unless`

Comment: Nah it's cool. I would work with `unless`. Never knew about that as I never liked `unless`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To add some other popular choices (@RSB: feel free to copy these into your answer):

Using '!':

```
if !Model.exists?(table_column: 'joe')
  # A single '!' negates
end
```

Using '==':

```
if Model.exists?(table_column: 'joe') == false
  # compared against false
end
```

Note that there are slight (but potentially dramatic) differences  in the approaches, search the web for "falsey", "truthy" or "truthiness" and your favorite programming language.

Which solution to choose depends a lot on your style and the expression you have at hand (the `my_value == false` one for example is really explicit and will not hit if `my_value = nil`).

Comment: Dont't do `== false` for checking whether a condition is not fulfilled! Ruby has two ways to represent falsehood: `FalseClass` and `NilClass`. With your approach, you catch only the former. The comparision **is** useful, if you work with three-valued logic. For instance, you have a function where the output can be *true*, *false* and *don't know*, and you decide to model this using `true`, `false` and `nil`. In this case, you would indeed compare by `... == false`.

Comment: @user1934428: exactly. :)