# Run code if x times if item present

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5

From my [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39242942/check-if-false-then-run-code), I cant seem to get what I want. Below explains a lot better:

```
external = ["apple"]
internal = ["grapes", "pear", "mangoes", "apple"]

external.each do |fruit|
 if not internal.include?("apple") # fruit will be in place of apple.
   puts "yes"
   # run code
 end
end
```

So far this is printing once. How to get it print three times? In English I'm saying if `apple` is present, leave `apple` alone, give me the others, and run the code below. If 4 items are there and one is `apple`, run code three times. If `apple` not present, run code 4 times.

I hope this is very clear. Thanks

**I need to be 100% precise**:

Internal is a Model (postgres)
External is shopify api (array)

I have saved shopify's product id in my database, `Bar`, on a column called `foo`.
`Bar.first.foo` gives me the shopify's id. `Bar` will have other object with/without the shopify id. So If shopify is there, give me the rest. This is why I came up with:

```
external.each do |fruit|
 if not internal.include?("apple") # fruit will be in place of apple.
   puts "yes"
   # run code
 end
end
```

**A precise edit of my code:**

The `external` is [shopify product response](https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/webhook).

```
external = # shopify's response (forget about the above example).
internal = Product.all # All of the user's products
```

So in my Product model, I have a product id. That id is for a shopify product. Example:

```
Product.first.product_id = # "8cd66767sssxxxxx"
```

In that same Model (Product), I have more objects, along with shopify product id. I need all objects except the id `8cd66767sssxxxxx`:

```
Product.last.product_id = # "BOOK" etc but not a shopify id.
```

**fl00r's answer works in my console, but not in the controller. Weird. This is what works for me.**

```
external.each do |e|
  internal.each do |i|
    puts i.product_id unless i.product_id == e.id.to_s
  end
end
```

Minor issue. On the first iteration, the `id` is included but does not on the second. Not sure what to do from here.

Comment: (internal - external).each { |fruit| puts 'yes' #your code }

Comment: so what is the output?

Comment: @fl00r `<Product:0x007fea45101da0>` x13 (all if the array). I expect x12.

Comment: You are iterating through a list with 1 element. Expected output should be empty. I am totally confused. `external.each` will have only one iteration. And it will omit any output as far as apple presents in internal list.

Comment: Im going to see if something is wrong with my code. Also, I may not be clear. I'll update with a replica of my code later. Thanks.

Comment: @fl00r Hi. I have made it clear what I wanted to do. See edit. Thanks.

Comment: My solution should fit your needs. I don't understand what's wrong with it

Comment: It should but its not excluding the matching product id

Comment: @fl00r In my console, you answer works but in my rails controller it does not. Weird. But because Im lazy, Ive found a solution. See edit. Does that uses less server processing?

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you do it this way?

```
(internal - external).each do |fruit| 
  puts 'yes' 
  #your code
end
```

Comment: Sorry, I may not be clear. It's a array object where the example is simplified. `external` is an api object while `internal` is my local db.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to rethink your external data structure. `Set` would fit better here (we will use `Hash` though):

```
external = ["apple"]
internal = ["grapes", "pear", "mangoes", "apple"]

external_hash = external.each_with_object({}){ |o, h| h[o] = true }

internal.each do |item|
  unless external_hash[item]
    p item
  end
end
#=> "grapes"
#=> "pear"
#=> "mangoes"
```

or you could filter your internal list first

```
internal_filtered = internal.reject{ |item| external_hash[item] }
internal_filtered.each do |item|
  p item
end
#=> "grapes"
#=> "pear"
#=> "mangoes"
```

Converting `Array` into `Hash` will cost `O(n)` to you and each following lookup will cost amortized `O(1)`.

So total complexity will be `O(n+m)`, where `n` is a size of an external list and `m` is a size of an internal list.

Comment: I do not need apple. I need to avoid apple and get the rest.

Comment: @Sylar do it vise verse then :)

Comment: Ok... let me see.

Comment: Im still getting all of internal.

Comment: maybe you confused output of `each` and your real block execution output?  Because `each` will output original `internal` array, but you should just ignore it.

Comment: I have made changes to my post.